# Can MPD see a multiple-track mkv parts as individual song?

Tags: mpd, music-player

I use MPD and I control it with `ncmpcpp` ncurses client. `ncmpcpp` is “itunes-like”, it mean that it have a tree-column presentation Artist—Album—Song. So, for operas (for example *The Magic Flute* of Mozart), I have one mkv with many tracks for all scenes this opera contain.

So, I would like MPD see all this mkv track as if it was in an individual file. In `ncmpcpp`, the scenes have to apear in the Song’s column and the name of the full opera in the album’s column.

Is this possible?